# How to get "nearest" element using django filter or someway

Tags: python, django

How to get "nearest" element using django filter or someway

currently i'm getting

> Specific_Place | Start_Time(period)
>
> 101 | 7
>
> 101 | 8
>
> 101 | 9
>
> 102 | 7
>
> 102 | 8
>
> 102 | 9

I want to print only nearest "Start_time"(period) like below how should I solve this problem?

> Specific_Place | Start_Time(period)
>
> 101 | 7
>
> 102 | 7

This is my django code

```
models.py----------------------------

    class Study(models.Model):
        Number_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
        Name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
        Grade_Point = models.FloatField(default=None)
        Time = models.CharField(max_length=10)
        Prof_Name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
        Class_People = models.IntegerField(default=None)
        Day = models.CharField(max_length=1)
        Start_Time = models.IntegerField()
        End_Time = models.IntegerField()
        Place = models.ForeignKey(PlaceName, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        Specific_Place = models.ForeignKey(Specific, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

views.py-----------------------------------------
    places = "Prime"
    empty_lecture_in_list=["101","102"]

    empty_lecture = Study.objects.filter(
    Place=places,
    Specific_Place__in=empty_lecture_in_list
    Day=4, #0~6 mon(0), tues(1), wed(2)... sun(6)
    Start_Time__gt=132 #this 132 means Time -> 132/12 -> 11 o'clock
    )

    for aa in empty_lecture_in:
        print(aa.Specific_Place)
        print(int(aa.Start_Time/12-8)) # this means period
```